# Using XLS files to store JBehave stories

Tags: xls, jbehave

I have based my new project with JBehave, Selenium, Maven and Spring from the etsy sample here : https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial/tree/master/etsy-selenium/java-spring

I'm really new to JBehave and I would like to know if there is a way to get it reading stories from XLS files ?

I think there is something to do with the String[] storyPaths() method that returns the stories name but I don't know how JBehave manages their content.

Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to change the storyPaths() method to be able to read stories title.

I also have my answer : I need to extend from org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromClasspath or org.jbehave.core.io.LoadFromURL classes to get stories content.